# after app is installed in the mobile it fails to open , app is crashing

Tags: android, kotlin

**in this app, I have created a recycler view and I m just trying to update data on the recycler view but my app is crashing without giving any error.
**when i m not passing any arraylist to the adapter in its primary constructor it is running well**
**Main Activity Kotlin code**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(),NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    //Variables
    private lateinit var drawerLayout : DrawerLayout
    lateinit var toggle : ActionBarDrawerToggle
    lateinit var navView : NavigationView
    lateinit var toolBar : androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    lateinit var adapter: MyAdapter
    lateinit var titles : ArrayList<String>
    lateinit var contents : ArrayList<String>

    //onCreate fun
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // toolbar support
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        // creating layout manager
        val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager

        //intiializing
        drawerLayout = drawer
        navView = navigation_view
        toolBar = toolbar
         titles = ArrayList<String>()
         contents = ArrayList<String>()
        update()
        adapter = MyAdapter(titles,contents)
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter

                                            // navView button click managed
        navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
        toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.open,R.string.close)
        toggle.isDrawerIndicatorEnabled = true
        toggle.syncState()

    }

    override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when(item.itemId){
           else->{
               Toast.makeText(this,"ButtonClicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
           }
        }

        return false
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.option_menu,menu)
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        if(item.itemId == R.id.settings){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Setting selected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
    private fun update(){
        titles.add("Hey")
        contents.add("hello")
        titles.add("Hey")
        contents.add("hello")
        titles.add("Hey")
        contents.add("hello")
        titles.add("Hey")
        contents.add("hello")
    }
}
```

**activity_main**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

   <include
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       layout="@layout/content_main"
       />
    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_menu"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_gravity = "start"
        />
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**Adapter class**

```
package com.example.mynotes.model

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.mynotes.R
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.single_note_view.view.*
import java.util.*

class MyAdapter(private val titles : ArrayList<String>, private val content : ArrayList<String> ) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
       val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.single_note_view,parent,false)
        return MyViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentTitle = titles[position]
        val currentContent = content[position]
        holder.content.text = currentContent
        holder.titles.text = currentTitle
        holder.view.setOnClickListener{

        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
       return titles.size
    }
}
class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
    val content : TextView = itemView.content
    val titles : TextView = itemView.titles
    lateinit var view : TextView
}
```

**content_main**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:background="@color/teal_700"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="79dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="174dp"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

**single item look for recycler view**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/noteCard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#7B1FA2"
        app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
        app:cardElevation="5dp"
        app:contentPadding="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="normal|italic"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/cardView"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cardView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
                app:cardElevation="5dp"
                app:contentPadding="5dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/menuIcon"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_vertical_bars_24"
                        tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/titles"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="2dp"
                        android:text="TextView"
                        android:textColor="@color/design_default_color_primary_dark"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/menuIcon"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        />

                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Logcat**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.mynotes, PID: 29432
    kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property view has not been initialized
        at com.example.mynotes.model.MyViewHolder.getView(MyAdapter.kt:35)
        at com.example.mynotes.model.MyAdapter.onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.kt:23)
        at com.example.mynotes.model.MyAdapter.onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.kt:12)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7254)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7337)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6194)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6460)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6300)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6296)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2330)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1631)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1591)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:668)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4309)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:4012)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4578)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19693)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6079)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1791)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1635)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1544)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19693)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6079)
        at androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1231)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19693)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6079)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19693)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6079)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1791)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1635)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1544)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19693)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6079)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19693)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6079)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1791)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1635)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1544)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19693)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6079)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:764)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19693)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6079)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2541)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2257)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1437)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6886)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1029)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:841)
2021-07-05 12:27:01.950 29432-29432/com.example.mynotes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:772)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1015)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:794)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6651)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824)
2021-07-05 12:27:02.001 29432-29432/com.example.mynotes I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 29432 SIG: 9
```

Comment: could show the crash log ？

Comment: please review again i have uploaded logcat data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is in your Adapter Class.
In the MyViewHolder class comment this line

```
lateinit var view : TextView
```

as you are not initializing it, so it is producing an exception when you are adding onClickListener to it in OnBindViewHolder Method

And also comment this line in the OnBindViewHolder method

```
 holder.view.setOnClickListener{

        }
```

Comment: what should i do if i want to create any empty view in viewHolder

Comment: just make a view and set it invisible. ' android:visibility="invisible" '